# Как добавить несколько переменных по условию в java

Tags: java, view

Есть `view`:

`public class Level2 extends View {`

Есть переменные:

```
int xx1 = 150; int yy1 = 100;//набор 1
int xx2 = 650; int yy2 = 120;//набор 2
int xx3 = 300; int yy3 = 240;//набор 3
```

Как сделать чтобы каждый набор переменных был доступен по условию, например:

```
if (1 == 1){int xx1 = 150; int yy1 = 100;//набор 1} 
if (1 == 2){int xx2 = 650; int yy2 = 120;//набор 2}
if (1 == 3){int xx3 = 300; int yy3 = 240;//набор 3}
```

Пытался добавлять так:

```
public void checkLines(){
    if (1 == 1){int xx1 = 150; int yy1 = 100;//набор 1} 
    if (1 == 2){int xx2 = 650; int yy2 = 120;//набор 2}
    if (1 == 3){int xx3 = 300; int yy3 = 240;//набор 3}
```

и вставлять в код `checkLines()`. Переменные недоступны почему-то.

Answer (score 1):

Изначально неправильный вопрос. Решили вот так - все работает!

```
   RelativeLayout layout = 
           (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.game_relativelayuot);
   List<View> levels = new ArrayList<>();
   levels.add(new Level1(this, getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE), layout));
   levels.add(new Level2(this, getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE), layout));
   levels.add(new Level3(this, getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE), layout));
   int ggr = 1;
   if(1==1){ggr = 1;};
   if(1==2){ggr = 2;};
   if(1==3){ggr = 3;};
   layout.addView(levels.get(ggr), 0);
```

Comment: Ээ.. `if(1==1)`, `if(1==2)`, `if(1==3)` - это что за такие условия?

Comment: Pavel , образно, не вписал переменные в которых будет что то , сразу указал какие данные ожидаются там . К примеру чтобы понятнее 1==1 чем value == 1 .   Конечно спустя время вижу свою ошибку - ведь я определял новые переменные. Не возвращал результат для необходимым переменных . Это я про сам вопрос. Сейчас я бы так не стал делать конечно.